# Use scrcpy to connect to multiple smartphones

Tags: scrcpy

I just learned how to use scrcpy. I successfully turned on ADB on the Android and am able to scrcpy to it from my PC. Now, I want to connect to multiple smartphones.

I notice it is a portable app, so is it a matter of duplicating multiple folders of scrcpy? Or can I connect to multiple phones from one instance of scrcpy?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If multiple devices are connected you can select the device to connect to by specify it's serial number. This is documented on the [scrcpy help page](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy). Therefore you can start one scrcpy instance per device.

> Multi-devices
>
> If several devices are listed in adb devices, you must specify the
> serial:

```
scrcpy --serial 0123456789abcdef 
scrcpy -s 0123456789abcdef # short
```

To get a detailed list of devices you can execute the command

```
adb devices -l
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves it. My issue seems to be outside the scope of this question. I Samsung Active2 that I can ping, but actively refused on port 5555 when I try telnet nor adb connect x.x.x.x:5555. I'm doing this via wireless as well.

Comment: @Sun ADB via wireless is disabled by default (and AFAIR reset with every reboot). Therefore you have to connect the device via USB ADB and enable ADB wireless first.